# how to insert node at exist xml file with php dom

Tags: php, xml, dom

I try to add node  at  in exist xml file but it's not work

number.xml

```
<numbers>
<number>1</number>
<number>2</number>
</numbers>
```

number.php

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml -> load('number.xml');
$xml_number = $xml->createElement("number");
$xml_number_text = $xml->createTextNode("3");
$xml_number->appendChild($xml_number_text);
$xml_numbers = $xml->getElementsByTagName('numbers');
$xml_numbers->appendChild($xml_number);
$xml->formatOutput=true;
$xml->save("number.xml") or die("Error");
?>
```

this is a error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::appendChild() in number.php
How to add number to numbers? I need it look like...

```
<numbers>
<number>1</number>
<number>2</number>
<number>3</number>
</numbers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
$xml_numbers = $xml->getElementsByTagName('numbers');
```

should be:

```
$xml_numbers = $xml->getElementsByTagName('numbers')->item(0);
```

Note, that `getElementsByTagName()` will always return an XMLNodeList Object, not a single node - even if just a single element was found, like in your case. You need to explicitly address the first element of that list using `->item(0)`.

Comment: OH! YES, I did it!!! Thank you very much.
but I can't vote. I have 1 repulation point :(
how can I do something for this point.